# Does tar preserve permissions if user IDs change?

Tags: linux, tar

I need to backup some data with the "p" option on tar command. The problem is the place I'm going to restore this data will have all the same users, but those users may have different IDs. Does that make any difference to tar or will it restore permissions correctly by user name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tar` records permissions based on the UID and GID, not on the string associated with them.  So if the UID on one server was 3300 and that was linked to 'bob', on the new server the file will be owned by the user who has the UID 3300.

Virtual everything (I want to say everything, but you can never be 100% sure) on UNIX uses the UID:GID values, because that's what is actually stored at the filesystem level.  The name is just a simple lookup in the passwd file, the underlying checks are done using the numeric values.

Comment: Ah, that is not good ... I guess in most situations it's suitable. Unfortunately, not for me ... Thank you, EightBitTony.

Comment: You most likely mean GID (group identifier), not GUID (Globally Unique Identifier).

Comment: GNU tar does save the user/group name data, too, because I can see it if I list an archive on a machine that doesn't have those users. There must be a way to get it to use that during extraction.

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. `tar` *does* record owner names.

Comment: tar on ubuntu 16.04+ clearly does _not_ store gid or uid... but instead the user/group names. This became a problem when I had to restore a backup of a server from a live environment that did not use the same name-id mapping. Upon booting into the restored system it was just a litany of permissions errors. I presume this to be the case on most GNU systems. The hacky solution I came up with was to over-write the passwd and group files in the live environment with those from the back up before running tar. Then promptly reboot to restore them.

Answer (score 75):

Summing up previous answers and adding some important information:

- When creating archives, `tar` will always preserve files' user and group ID, *unless* told otherwise with `--owner=NAME`, `--group=NAME`. In either case, each file will always have an associated *numeric* user and group ID.
- GNU `tar`, and perhaps other versions of `tar`, *also* store the user and group *names*, unless `--numeric-owner` is used. `bsdtar` also stores user and group names by default, but it had no support for `--numeric-owner` option when *creating* archives until version 3.0 (note that it supported the option when *extracting* archives since much longer).
- When extracting as a *regular user*, all files will *always* be owned by the user. And it can't be any different, since extracting a file means creating a new one on the filesystem, and a regular user cannot create a file and give ownership to someone else.
- When extracting as *root*, `tar` will by default restore ownership of extracted files, *unless* `--no-same-owner` is used, which will give ownership to root himself.
- In GNU tar, bsdtar, and perhaps other versions of `tar`, restored ownership is done by user (and group) *name*, if that information is in the archive *and* there is a matching user in the destination system. Otherwise, it restores by ID. If `--numeric-owner` option is provided, user and group names are ignored and IDs are used. In either case, whenever numeric IDs are used, a matching user and group does *not* need to exist in the system.
- Permissions and timestamps are also saved to the archive, and restored by default, unless options `--no-same-permissions` and/or `--touch` are used. When extracted by the user, user's `umask` is *subtracted* from permissions unless `--same-permissions` is used.
- `--preserve-permissions` and `--same-permissions` are aliases, and have the same functionality as `-p`

Hope this helps clarify the issue! :)

Comment: Excellent answer; Answers this question as well as every other  question that may arise on the subject.

Comment: It should be noted that only recent versions of GNU `tar` allow specifying arbitrary names in `--owner` or `--group`, in the past `tar` did a gratuitous lookup in the current machine `/etc/passwd` and refused to run if there was no match.

Comment: What happens if you create an archive with specified name with `--owner` but also added in the `--numeric-owner` flag? How does tar deal with these competing requirements?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai : `--owner` and `--numeric-owner` are not mutually exclusive, and serve very distinct purposes: `--owner=USERNAME` will override the files and dirs owner(s) when archiving the files, while `--numeric-owner` will simply not store the username, just his numerical ID.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to transfer files between two systems, rsync will by default set the permissions by username instead of uid, looking at the usernames at both ends.  Only if the user doesn't exist on one of the systems will it copy it with the uid, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the OP's question, but anyone asking the OP's question ought to learn this, too.

Answer (score 5):

User the --same-owner option to GNU tar. See http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Attributes.html

Comment: This is documented as the default for superusers, and seems to answer the OP's question differently than the accepted answer. (The link says that when GNU tar restores using --same-owner, it looks first for *names* in /etc/passwd.) The only outstanding issue is whether the OP's version of tar implements --same-owner.

Comment: The OP is using some Linux distro so better than even chance of using GNU tar, methinks. And going by the documentation it *is* possible while the accepted answer indicates it's not...

Comment: @Catcall - sorry, i accepted the answer without even having a chance to test it. Somethimes i just blindly trust people. Still, the person who answered was kinda right, since i wasn't restoring with "--same-owner" and then you've added to the answer. Too bad i can't accept both. I'm using debian squeeze which indeed does support "--same-owner". Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Marius: I'm pretty sure you can change the accepted answer whenever you like. (I'll just point out that I haven't provided any answers to this question, only comments. I don't have any rep at stake.)