# What happens if an owner on duplicity restore does not exist?

Tags: permissions, duplicity

Similar to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/445504/535226), I would like to know how duplicity behaves if an owner of files / directories does not exist on restore? And what happens if the owner does not exist on backup? By non-existence I refer to the absence of an entry in /etc/passwd.

Background: Docker bind volume mount paths on the host system sometimes only have a UID, but no user name if a user only exists in the container (e.g. as described [here](https://github.com/tomsquest/docker-radicale) under `Option 0.`. The question is whether duplicity can just restore UID / GID even if there is no matching /etc/passwd entry.

Answer (score 0):

on the sight of filesystem it doesn't care you can try this like

```
adduser deleteme
su deleteme -c "touch testfile" 
tar cf bkp.tar testfile 
deluser deleteme
tar xf bkp.tar
ls testfile
```

as you can see that file it will keep the uid of deleteme and you have to change it manually, thats it

and in case you need to ajust the ownership you can use

```
chown username:group testfile
```

it also works with

```
chown uid:gid testfile
```

to chown a folder And subfolders

```
chown -R name:group folder/
```

hope i could help you